# Kolmogorov - M. Riesz - Fréchet Theorem

Tags: lp-spaces

*I need help to understand, some steps of the proof of this theorem.*

**(Kolmogorov-M. Riesz-Fréchet)** Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a bounded set in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)$ with $1\leq p < \infty$. Assume that

\begin{equation}
   \lim\limits_{|h|\longrightarrow 0 }\|\tau_hf-f\|_p=0 \ uniformly 
 \; in \, f \in \mathcal{F}, 
  \end{equation}

i.e 
         $\forall \varepsilon >0 \; \exists \delta >0$ such that $\|\tau_hf-f\|_p<\varepsilon \; \forall f \in \mathcal{F}, \; \forall h \in \mathbb{R}^N$ with $|h|<\delta$. 
        Then the closure of $\mathcal{F}_{|\Omega}$ is compact for any measurable set in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ with finite measure.

*Well, you can find it in Haim Brezis, Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and PDE. page 111*

In step 1: We claim that 
    \begin{equation}
   \|(\rho_n*f)-f\|_{L^p(\mathbb{R}^N)}\leq \varepsilon \ \forall f \in \mathcal{F}, \ \forall n > 1/n.  \label{4.26_kolmogorov_23}
  \end{equation}

And we have, 
    \begin{equation*}
  \begin{split}
   |(\rho_n*f)(x)-f(x)|  &\leq \int |(f(x-y)-f(x))\rho_n(y)dy|\\
         &\leq \left[ \int |(f(x-y)-f(x))|^p\rho_n(y)dy \right]^{1/p} 
  \end{split}
 \end{equation*}
By Hölder´s inequality

*So, i can´t understand, how use the Hölder´s inequality in the last inequality, please help me!!*

Answer (score 4):

If $\rho_n$ is a probability density function and $\mu_n(B)=\int_B\rho_n(x)dx$, then
\begin{align}\int |f(x-y)-f(x)|\rho_n(y)dy&=\int|f(x-y)-f(x)|d\mu_n\\
&\le \left(\int|f(x-y)-f(x)|^{p}d\mu_n\right)^{1/p}\left(\int |1|^{q}d\mu_n\right)^{1/q}\\
&=\left(\int|f(x-y)-f(x)|^{p}\rho_n(y)dy\right)^{1/p}
\end{align}

I know that you didn't mention that $\rho_n$ was a density but given that $\rho_n$ is not written as to the power of p after Hölder and the q seems to be missing this is my best guess of what happened.

Comment: $\rho_n$ is a mollifier, then $$\rho_n\in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^N), \ supp\ \rho_n \subset \overline{B(0,1/n)},\ \int \rho_n=1,\ \rho_n \geq 0,\ on\ \mathbb{R}^N.$$

Comment: $\int \rho_n(x)dx=1$ and $\rho_n\ge0$ make it a density and my answer works

Comment: Yes!! And Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

$$\int|f(x-y)-f(x)|\rho_n(y)dy=\int|f(x-y)-f(x)|{(\rho_n(y))}^{1/p}{(\rho_n(y))^{1-1/p}}dy$$ Then use the Holder's inequality and $\int \rho_n=1$, get the result.